# Python initializing attributes of objcts

Tags: python, class, attributes

if have the following problem: I need to program a class called filament in Python. An object filament has the attribute `head`, that also needs to have other two attributes, `up` and `down`. This is what I did:

```
class filament(object):
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.head = start
        head.up = 1
        head.down = 1
fil = filament(1)
```

If I run it I get: `"NameError: name 'head' is not defined"`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you assign start to head and start is an int object. another problem is that you try to access head which is not a local variable. you have to call self.head ... at least head should be a dict like self.head = {} than add keys like self.head['up'] = 1 and so on. another option is to create a class head with the attributes start, up, down.

Comment: Can you describe more what you want to do with the 'head' variable exactly? Your syntax at the moment is wrong, need to use `self.head.up = 1`. That resolves the NameError, but will cause a new problem due to `self.head` being an int and not an object with the attribute up or down.

Comment: I want to have an object filament, which has a head given by some coortinates ( now 1 in 1D). A particle can attach to a head from 'up' or from 'down', and If they indeed attach depends from some magnitude (in my example =1 in both cases) associated to 'up' or 'down'.

Comment: I would like to be able to call:
fil.head # get head coordinate //// and also:
fil.head.up #get up magnitude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question

> you need object filament has the attribute head, that also needs to have
>   other two attributes, 'up' and 'down'.

For that you can create a class with attribute `up` and `down`. Ie, something like this.

```
class Head(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.up, self.down = args


class filament(object):
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.head = Head(1, 1)

fil = filament()
print(fil.head.up)
print(fil.head.down)
```

You can also use `namedtuple` from `collections` module to get the same behaviour.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Head = namedtuple('Head', ['up', 'down'])


class filament(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Head(1, 1)

fil = filament()
print(fil.head.up)
print(fil.head.down)
```